# How to get enum type from another project in solution?

Tags: wpf, types, converters

I have a wpf converter which Im passing a parameter of the enum type for which it converts the bound integer value to the enumerated text. In order to do this so its generic I need to pull the enum type for a passed in qualified type name.

```
namespace SomeOtherProject.MyClass
//
public enum MyTypes
{
   MyType1 = 0,
   MyType2 = 100,
   MyType3 = 200,
   MyType4 = 300
}


namespace SomeProject.SomeClass
{
//
var typeName = SomeOtherProject.MyClass.MyTypes;
type = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

This does not retrieve the type and produces a null.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` to get a `System.Type` for any type.  It doesn't matter if it's in the same project or not (as long as the other project is referenced):

```
Type theType = typeof(SomeOtherProject.MyClass.MyTypes);
```

Comment: It still produced a null so I ended up with a custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the custom converter I used to produce the translation from an enum int value to its text value.

WPF Xaml gridviewdatacolumn snippet

```
... DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductTypeId, Converter={StaticResource IntEnumValueToDisplayNameConverter1}, ConverterParameter=Solution1.SomePath.SomeOtherPath\, Solution1\.SomePath\, Version\=1\.0\.0\.0\, Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=null}"
```

Converter code example:

```
namespace Solution1.SomePath.Converters
{
   using System;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Windows.Data;

   internal class IntEnumValueToDisplayNameConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         try
         {
            if (value == null || parameter == null)
               return null;

            var type = GetTypeFromParameter(parameter);

            if (type == null)
               return null;

            var enumValue = Enum.Parse(type, value.ToString(), true);

            if (enumValue == null)
               return null;

            return enumValue.ToString();
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            return null;
         }
      }

      private static Type GetTypeFromParameter(object parameter)
      {
         if (parameter == null)
            return null;

         Type type;

         if (parameter is Type)
         {
            type = parameter as Type;

            if (type == null || !type.IsEnum)
               return null;
         }
         else if (parameter is string)
         {
            // Must be fully qualified assembly name to work
            // Example: Solution1.SomePath.SomeOtherPath, Solution1.SomePath, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
            var typeName = parameter as string;

            if (typeName.IsEmpty())
               return null;

            type = Type.GetType(typeName);

            if (type == null || !type.IsEnum)
               return null;
         }
         else
            return null;

         return type;
      }
   }
}
```